# Can anyone Jew today prove that they did not contact Tumas Mes?

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

In a shiur the Rabbi stated that today, "basically every Jew is impure" bc of contact with dead bodies (not just by visiting cemeteries or morgues, but especially also via unseen bodies buried deep in the ground).

Are there Jews that can conclusively show they themselves never contacted tumas mes?

While proving a negative is hard, maybe along the lines of "I was careful around obvious dead bodies, and I stayed all my life w/i the radius of this block and we have a tradition that there was never a Jewish bodies in the ground below this block."

Comment: What the rabbi said used to be obviously true because people generally died at home. Nowadays with hospital care it's actually relatively possible that someone never contracted corpse impurity.

Comment: Don't think so @DoubleAA. Most, if not all, people have been inside a hospital building at some time in their lives (birth, bikur holim, chas vechalilah illness) and there is a very high chance that at the same time there was a dead body in the same building. That gives a very high chance of tum'ah by ohel (being under the same roof). The person was probably unaware of this at the time. This also applies to limbs, e.g. in an operating theatre.

Comment: @epicentre sure most. It's just reasonably possible at this point that someone hasn't. Also hospitals aren't all always Tamei